# rename a matrix column which as no initial names with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to rename the columns of a matrix that has no names in dplyr :

```
set.seed(1234)
v1 <- table(round(runif(50,0,10)))
v2 <- table(round(runif(50,0,10)))

library(dplyr)
bind_rows(v1,v2) %>% 
  t 
   [,1] [,2]
0     3    4
1     1    9
2     8    6
3    11    7
5     7    8
6     7    1
7     3    4
8     6    3
9     3    6
10    1   NA
4    NA    2
```

I usually use `rename` for that with the form `rename(new_name=old_name)` however because there is no `old_name` it doesn't work.  I've tried:

```
rename("v1","v2")
rename(c("v1","v2")
rename(v1=1, v2=2)
rename(v1=[,1],v2=[,v2])
rename(v1="[,1]",v2="[,v2]")
rename_(.dots = c("v1","v2"))
setNames(c("v1","v2"))
```

none of these works.

I know the base R way to do it (`colnames(obj) <- c("v1","v2")`) but I'm specifically looking for a `dplyr`way to do it.

Comment: `...%>% as.tibble() %>% rename(...)` should be fine. Or even ```bind_rows(v1,v2) %>% t() %>% `colnames<-`(c('A', 'B'))```

Comment: `dplyr::rename` needs `names`, not `colnames`, hence works with `data.frame` or `tibble`. Then you can use the `rename` or, maybe more convenient and also using the pipe, `setNames`. A simple `as.data.frame` does the trick and you have the columns `V1` & `V2`.

Comment: You have a matrix. You need to convert it to data.frame or tibble. If you convert it to tibble, as Sotos suggested, you will see V1 and V2 as column names. If you convert your data to data frame, you will see X1 and X2 as column names.  So you have old names for rename().

Comment: Thanks all for the quick answer.  I like the `'colnames<-'(c('A', 'B'))` call as it maintain my matrix class.  However it's quite an ugly call...  Switching to a DF also work.

Comment: @Sotos, if you want, add you comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one with `magrittr`:

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(v1,v2) %>% 
  t %>%
  magrittr::set_colnames(c("new1", "new2"))
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to use `rename` you need to have some sort of a list (like a data frame or a tibble). So you can do two things. You either convert to `tibble` and use `rename` or use `colnames` and leave the structure as is, i.e.

```
new_d <- bind_rows(v1,v2) %>% 
  t() %>% 
  as.tibble() %>% 
  rename('A' = 'V1',  'B' = 'V2')

#where
str(new_d)
#Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':  11 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ A: int  3 1 8 11 7 7 3 6 3 1 ...
# $ B: int  4 9 6 7 8 1 4 3 6 NA ...

Or

new_d1 <- bind_rows(v1,v2) %>% 
  t() %>% 
  `colnames<-`(c('A', 'B')) 

#where

str(new_d1)
# int [1:11, 1:2] 3 1 8 11 7 7 3 6 3 1 ...
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  ..$ : chr [1:11] "0" "1" "2" "3" ...
#  ..$ : chr [1:2] "A" "B"
```